# Configure CCNET on windows 10

Tags: windows, iis, cruisecontrol.net

I am attempting to setup CCNET 1.8.5 on a windows 10 machine. 
I have IIS installed and when I installed CCNET it stated that I needed to setup the virtual directory manually. 
I go into IIS and under Default Web Site created the ccnet application. I pointed it to the correct physical path and the default application pool. Test settings completes successfully.
When I go to Browse the page however, I get an error 500.19, and it points to the web.config file and appears to have a problem with the handlers at line 67.

Line 67 is just the opening tag for `<handlers`>

I verified that the file is properly formatted. The next line is the default settings. 
 68:       `<add verb="*" path="*.aspx" type="ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.WebDashboard.MVC.ASPNET.HttpHandler,ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.WebDashboard" name="CCNetHttpHandler"`/>

I have compared the settings on this new windows 10 machine with existing windows 7 machines and everything correlates.

Does anyone with a deeper knowledge of IIS and CCNET have any ideas of what I need to do? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not certain what changed, but now CCNET is working correctly. I wish I knew what I looked at correctly to get it to work. :)

EDIT: I found the problem. I started over and realized that when I enable IIS in Windows 10, none of the ASP.NET features are enabled. I had to find them elsewhere in the list of features, enable them and finally CCNET will work. Hopefully this helps someone else.